# JAVA JPA error 401: "Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Tags: java, c#, jpa, oauth-2.0, http-status-code-401

I'm using JAVA JPA API which I call from my C# app. C# -> JAVA API call methods are generated by OpenAPI-generator. I use Oauth2 for authentication. The C# -> Oauth2 seems to be working fine after the call I get the access Token, but when sending GET request (or any other that requires authentication) I get an error "Full authentication is required to access this resource".

Postman -> Oauth2 -> JAVA    works fine.

Things I checked:

1. Request/server path/ip is good
2. API version/code on server is up to date
3. Oauth2 server returns token
4. Oauth2 token is valid and working (copy pasted from C# while debugging to Postman to double check)

I need more ideas guys

Comment: How are you setting the authorization header? Could you post some code showing how you're sending requests to the JAVA API?

Comment: Man, you are my hero... The autogenerated API methods did not have the part that added my token to header. Now I'll just have to figure: why that happened

Answer (score 1):

[solved] In JAVA JPA @RestController forgot to add @SecurityRequirement(name = "oauth2Security") which resulted in OpenAPI-generator generating methods that did not added tokens to the headers.